# Pasar variables de Laravel a Vue usando VITE

Tags: laravel, vue.js

estoy haciendo un CRUD, y estoy en la parte para crear la vista de Edit de un registro. Lo que hago es que te redirijan a la vista de Laravel y usando VITE te pegue encima la vista de Vue.

Vista de Laravel

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app_estrategias_edit"></div>

    @vite('resources/js/app.js')
</body>
</html>
```

Controlador

```
public function edit(Estrategia $estrategia){
    return view('estrategias.edit', compact( 'estrategia' ));
}
```

Componente en Vue

```
<template>
   <h2>Hola</h2>
</template>
```

app.js

```
import './bootstrap';

import { createApp } from 'vue';

import app_estrategias_edit from './marketing/estrategias/edit.vue';

createApp(app_estrategias_edit)
      .mount('#app_estrategias_edit')
```

Y bueno eso seria lo referente a esa parte, montó el componente Vue mediante vite en la vista de Laravel. Pero claro, quiero usar la variable estrategia que paso en el compact a la vista. El punto es poder pasar la información de la estrategia a editar, al componente de Vue. Por ahora lo único que se me ocurre es tomar el id en el componente directamente de la url, pero me parece una solución fea. Gracias, saludos